# git command to get sets of 3 files that frequently change together at least four times

Tags: git, github

I want to know how I can find sets of  3 files that frequently changed together at least four times in one project.
Im using git on my terminal in mac iOS.
Im a beginner in using git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the set of files, I used this command

***git log --stat***

Then, saved the output in txt file and use python code to find the sets

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is actually a git command to handle what you want to achieve. You may check the [git-extras package](https://github.com/tj/git-extras) to see if they have a git command that suits your needs.

Some other useful commands that you may want to check are the following:

## Git Effort

`git-effort` lists all your repository files and number of commits they were involved in. You may also ignore files with `less than 4 commits` by doing:

```
`git-effort --above 4`.
```

## Git Log

You can track the commits of a single file using `git log`. Just use this command instead:

```
`git log --follow <filename>`
```

## Git diff-tree

You can list the files changed in a particular commit using this command.

```
 git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r <commit>
```

Perhaps, you can make your own script for your specific need by combining these commands (or some other commands from `git` or `git-extras` if the command that you need still does not exist.